# Find Binary Value Within ASCII String

Tags: python, string, binary, full-text-search, ascii

I have a data file that when printed outputs a series of characters along these lines:

> @ao��B��@�a��z�I{�@�M�C�cID
>    ...ect

I also have a binary value that has been extracted from this data file but I am unsure of at which point in the file. So given that I can read in the data using

```
  with open(self.filename, mode='rb') as data_file:
                self._file_contents = data_file.read()
```

I have been attempting to search for the index starting position of the binary value within the large string representing the file.

```
[m.start() for m in re.finditer(binary, data_file._file_contents]
```

I have attempted this with `binary` as a binary string (eg. 10011010) and using `str(int(binary,2))` to convert it to an integer string value searchable within the file. 
None of this has worked so I'm questioning my own logic and reason. If you know how you would find the index of a binary value, given you are 100% certain it is there within the file, please let me know how you would do so. Thanks

Comment: I think you're confusing two meanings of "binary" here: base-2 representation of a number (like `10011010` is 154 in binary), vs. "not text" (like `"@ao��"` in Python 3 or `'@ao��'` in Python 2 is binary data in a bytes or string).

Comment: Could you please expand on "binary data in a bytes or string" ?

Comment: The contents of a `bytes`/`str` object are sometimes intended to be interpreted as encoded (or just ASCII) text, like `b"Foo: bar\n"`, but they're also sometimes _not_ intended to be interpreted as text, like `"@ao��"`, or the contents of a JFIF image. The latter case is referred to as "binary data". It's not binary because it's in base-2, it's binary because its meaning is non-text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
binary = "\x22"  # <- this is what binary should look like
[m.start() for m in re.finditer(binary, data_file._file_contents)]
```

you can convert it if you have the intvalue of say 77 by using `binary = chr(77)`

if you have the hexvalue `77=0x4d` you can just do `binary="\x4d"`

if the value is greater than 0xff you will need unichar `binary = unichr(257)`
and you will need to use unicode strings (`257=0x0101`) `binary = u"\u0101"` or `binary="\x01\x01"`

Comment: How do I convert it to the "\x22" form? What is this form anyway? The data is in 32bit slices, so the largest value would be 0xffffffff and these slices are all concatenated and stored in the original data file. So given for example I wish to find 0xffffffff  or 1111...111 or 4294967295 in the large string given the large string from the file is formatted in the @ao��B way? Thank you for your help

Comment: the � is not helpful because that tells us nothing...to see what the data actually looks like use `repr(data_file.read())` that will show you the binary escape sequences .. so if you wanted to find `0xffffff` , then binary would be `binary="\xff\xff\xff"` since in a string (or bytearray) each "character" or byte is only one byte wide (ie `0x00-0xff`)

Comment: So the best course of action would be to take the binary value (ex. 10011) convert it to hex, from there to the "\xff\xff\xff" bytearray style and then search for that within the repr(data_file._file_contents) ?

Comment: More so I was wondering if there's a more direct way of getting it in "\xff\xff\xff" form?

Comment: The Unicode part of this answer doesn't work unless you happen to know that the value will be 32-bit aligned (because Unicode regexps don't search for half of one character and half of the next), and that your platform uses UTF-32 rather than UTF-16 for Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

> More so I was wondering if there's a more direct way of getting it in "\xff\xff\xff" form?

Yes. This kind of thing is exactly what the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module is for:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('<I', 4294967295)
'\xff\xff\xff\xff'
>>> struct.pack('<I', 1234567)
'\x87\xd6\x12\x00'
```

But the important part here is that you have to know what format you're looking for. The code above is treating each number as a little-endian unsigned 32-bit C integer, which is a pretty common format to use for cramming numbers into binary data, but certainly not the only one.

If you want to write the literal values in hex (base 16) or binary (base 2) instead of decimal, of course you can; as far as Python is concerned, `0b10011` and `13` are the same thing—the number 13. So:

```
>>> struct.pack('<I', 0b10011)
'\x13\x00\x00\x00'
>>> struct.pack('<I', 0xabcd)
'\xcd\xab\x00\x00'
```

But if the only reason you have numbers in base 2 is that you called some function that turns a number into a base-2 representation, just don't call that function.